# Prompt not asking for all users

Tags: excel, vba, popup, prompt

Hi all hope you can help me, few weeks back I was assisted with getting a report generated for my workplace and now that it has been released for testing a few issues have came up - for myself the report works - promps read only and works fine, however when a manager runs the program it open's with no read only prompt - this needs to be either opened as read only or prompted to read only ans any changes made must not be saved as its only to collate data from the selected workbook any advice ? the code I have is below.

````
Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim Filechosen As Boolean
    Dim Savebutton As Boolean

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    
    fd.Filters.Clear
    fd.Filters.Add "Old Excel Files", "*.xls"
    fd.Filters.Add "New Excel Files", "*.xlsx"
    fd.Filters.Add "macro Excel Files", "*.xlsm"
    fd.Filters.Add "any Excel Files", "*.xl*"
    
    fd.FilterIndex = 4
    
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        fd.InitialFileName = "work allocation/teamcases/bf/"
        
    Filechosen = fd.Show
    

    If Not Filechosen Then
        MsgBox " No File Selected"
        
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    fd.Execute
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   



End Sub```
````

Comment: the read only prompt is file specific and not macro specific, when the file is saved with a different name it may lose the read only prompt option. If they file gets uploaded to a sharepoint it also loses read only prompt as online files get auto saved. You mentioned "the file was released" some may be changing the name of the file and causing the issue. If the file is 100% dependent on a Macro to be useful, ad an Open macro that will change the file to ReadOnly, works really well.

Comment: the issue I'm having is that the files are on SharePoint, and the file name changes each month so has a new locations meaning the above process is the only method I know that will allow the files to be accessed, what I was wanting to know is if its possible to have the mso File Dialog box have a preset as read only - if not Ill have to retype the macro order on how it actions on the document in use